# accessing the contents of a kivy GridLayout by coordinates?

Tags: python, kivy, grid-layout

Is there a way to access the contents of a kivy `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` by coordinates, like accessing the element of the second row, third column.

If not, which I'm afraid is the case, is there something in kivy I could use instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can check all `children` of a layout widget in a loop, if one of them returns `True` for the [`self.collide_point(x,y)`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point) method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen "[simple table layout](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.simpletablelayout)" in the Garden? It says "SimpleTableLayout.cell(row, col) returns widget at that position in the grid" within the description. You should give it a try!